# What is the Fourier Transform of a weighted Dirac comb?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I have the follwowing Dirac comb:
\begin{equation*}
\mu=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^{n}\delta_{(n,0)}
\end{equation*}
and i would like to know what $\widehat{\mu}$ ist.
I know that $\widehat{\delta_{\mathbb{Z}}}= \delta_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is.
But i dont think this works here.
So i looked up how to Fourier Transform the normal dirac comb.
First you take the Fourier series $\mu(t)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{inw_{0}t}$,
where $w_{0}=\frac{2\pi}{T}$. In this case $T=2$. But at this point I'm not too sure what to do.
Because I'dont know if i can take the $(-1)^{n}$ in the sum or not? And if there are in it, what ist $\mathcal{F}((-1)^{n})$. Because the next step would be to take the Fourier Transform on both sides.
So that means:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(\mu(t))=\mathcal{F}(\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{inw_{0}t})
\end{equation}
So my Question is , is this the right way and what to do with $(-1)^{n}$?

Comment: The notation $\delta_{(n,0)}$ means $\delta_{(n,0)}(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ with $x=(n,0)$.

Comment: So do you mean $\widehat{\mu}=0$?

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}=\{,,,(-2,0),(-1,0),(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)...\}?$ If so, why not just write $\delta_n(x)$ which is equivalent to $\delta(x-n)$? Also, the Dirac delta function never evaluates to the value $1$, rather $\delta(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\land x\ne0$ and $\delta(0)$ is generally undefined. So it isn't apparent to me that you're really referring to the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$, or that your sum is really equivalent to the Dirac comb which for the case $T=1$ is defined as $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_n(x)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x-n)$.

Comment: Assuming the Fourier transform is defined as

$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, e^{i 2 \pi x \omega} \, dx\tag{1},$$

the term-wise Fourier transform of

$$\mu(x)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n\, \delta_n(x)\tag{2}$$

where $\delta_n(x)$ refers to the Dirac delta function $\delta(x-n)$ is

$$\hat{\mu}(\omega)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n\, e^{i 2 \pi n \omega}\tag{3}.$$

Comment: I originally evaluated this result by splitting the sum as

$$\hat{\mu}(\omega)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{-1} (-1)^n\, e^{i 2 \pi n \omega}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, e^{i 2 \pi n \omega}=\frac{1}{1+e^{2 i \pi  \omega }}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2 i \pi  \omega }}=0\tag{4},$$

but after further investigation I now suspect this result is actually the shifted Dirac comb

$$\hat{\mu}(\omega)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta\left(\omega-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{5}$$

which evaluates to zero everywhere except at $\omega=n+\frac{1}{2}$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I believe the sum needs to be evaluated as $$\hat{\mu}(\omega)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=-N}^N (-1)^n\, e^{i 2 \pi  n \omega}\right)=1+\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \cos\left(2 \pi n \left(\omega-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right)\tag{6}$$ which indeed does look like the Fourier series for a shifted Dirac comb.

Comment: I thought about this maybee, my question was a little bit false. I think $\delta_{(n,0)}$ should be a dirac measure. So i have the sum of a dirac measures.

Comment: It does appear some of your terminology is inconsistent. I was thinking your definition seemed more consistent with the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) $\delta_{x,n}$ than the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta_n(x)$, but I've seen other's confuse $\delta(0)=1$ with $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\, dx=1$, so I wasn't sure of your real intent. I based my comments above on your reference to the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) in the title.

Comment: It seems to me, that one can write $(-1)^n$ as $e^{i2\pi\frac{1}{2}x}$ and then use the shift theorem of the Fourier Transform, along with the knowledge of the transform pair $\widehat{\delta_{\mathbb{Z}}}= \delta_{\mathbb{Z}}$.  You should end up with a shifted comb as the transform.

Comment: Your sum seems somewhat analogous to the [discrete measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure#Definition_and_properties) $\mu=\sum\limits_i a_i\, \delta_{s_i}$ except you violate the restriction $a_i\in[0, \infty]$.

Comment: Okay if i use the shift Theorem, then i should get $\delta_{\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: What would be if you have $(-2)^{n}$ then you could write $2^{n}e^{i2\pi\frac{1}{2}n}$. What would then the Fourier Transform, because only with shift Theorem it is not done.